# Appcache manifest downloads all files but still unable to access offline unless they have been accessed online

Tags: html

I have successfully created an appcache manifest that is downloading all of the website content. I have checked this through chrome dev and it's all working.

The issue I am having now is that even although the entire website has been cached, I am unable to access the cached pages when offline, unless I had accessed them online.

I am using Apache and accessing the website via an iPad using safari browser.

I have an idea that this may be due to the server not allowing access to cached pages unless they had been accessed online as some kind of security measure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if your files are in PHP or ASP this will not work.

It need to be JavaScript or other files that can be run localy like Image, HTML.